# BrowserComponent with Infiniteloop

Tags: browser, codenameone

How do I add an Infinite progress till the WebPage is fully loaded?

```
 Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    final BrowserComponent wb = new BrowserComponent();
    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);

    final Dialog ipDlg = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();
    wb.setURL("https://www.codenameone.com");
    wb.addWebEventListener("onLoad", new ActionListener() {

   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
});


    hi.show();
    ipDlg.dispose();
```

above is the code I am using.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work since dialog is literally a separate Form. So the browser component will never load and won't show what's going on below.

You can use an `InteractionDialog` which is just a `Container` in the layered pane. This means the browser will keep loading and you can draw on top of it. Just add the `InfiniteProgress` into the `InteractionDialog` and show it.

Comment: do you have any implementation of this?

Comment: No, this isn't something I tried but it should work just the same as what you did only with `InteractionDialog` instead of `Dialog`.